# Is it possible to use URLRequestHeader with HTTPS

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

I'm currently using URLRequestHeader to upload mp3 data from an AIR desktop app using code similar to this...

```
appheader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
urlRequest = new URLRequest(http://www.blah.com/etc);
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(appheader);
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
```

I'm now having to update all my URL's to use HTTPS, but according to the AS3 docs, it looks like URLRequestHeader is only usable with HTTP calls.

[AS3 docs](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html)

Would anyone know how I can get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Mark

Comment: Why don't you just try it and tell us how did it go? The documentation does not explicitly state that HTTPS is not supported but HTTP is, and HTTPS is just a security layer over plain text HTTP, so as long as both client and server support HTTPS, everything that is true for HTTP will be true for HTTPS too.

Comment: @crooksy88 You only need a workaround if your above code didn't work on HTTPS server.

Comment: Thanks for your input so far. This wasn't made clear in my original post but I have tried this.

Comment: I have an existing AIR desktop app that successfully uploads and saves mp3 data to my server via a http: url. When I change the URL to https: the data is not uploaded/saved.

There are no server or php errors logged and using Fiddler to see what traffic is sent I see nothing. That app seemingly doesn't send anything.

If I upload mp3 data via https: using the Postman app this DOES work. So from that I am concluding the server and SSL certificate are valid and the issue lies with AIR not being able to send the mp3 data via https.

Comment: The app does successfully send other text/xml formatted data via https to the same domain.

Comment: No IDE to test here but... Maybe try as `"Content-type", "audio/mpeg"` for MP3, since it was accepting XML as `octet-stream`. Though logical thinking is that octet-stream should work for any file data because it's in bytes format.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion VC.One. Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue.